# alt attribute malfunction

Tags: alt

I have a question regarding the alt text function.
alt="" become visible in my Wordpress theme but the value shown is from title field .is that normal ? 
LE : This [link](https://github.com/wpshower/expositio/blob/master/tmpl_single.php) contail the code source of this free expositio theme.It looks like it's made pretty different on the alt/title part.Please watch this part : `$strResultGallery .=  '<td>'.'<img alt="'.$row_img->post_title.'" src="'.$strThumb.'" />';                                        $strResultGallery   .=  '<h5>'.$row_img->post_title.'</h5>';                                        $strResultGallery   .=  '</td>';` Here the "magic" happens. If you fill the alt field (from image edit tab), in the source code alt="" will be empty.Instead of this, If we fill the title field (also in the image edit tab) this will appear in the source code as alt attribute (because of `img alt="'.$row_img->post_title.'"`).More than that, `<h5>'.$row_img->post_title.'</h5>'` will make that alt="" atribute to appear as a title , visible on the page.These things are the same in the demo as well [link](http://expositio.wpshower.com/?p=6).Having said that, the code must be rewrited in order to have the functions alt/title in the regular way.If someone can please help , ... Thank you

Comment: You could remove the alt attribute altogether, which would decrease accessibility. The alt text will show if the picture is unavailable... That's the point of alt text!

Comment: thanks , I just made that but the images are gone for good :) Anyway, I am looking for a solution because as far as I know (hope I'm not wrong) , alt text is pretty good for seo - is that correct ? I need to force somehow the alt attribute to display the alt text , that's the point but unfortunately I am not so good in coding :P

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that I understand what you are trying to accomplish. You WANT the alt text to be rendered on the page?

Comment: sorry, I'll try to be more explicit.In my case , on that Wordpress theme (expositio), it looks like the alt atribute doesen't work properly.I just want that alt atribute to work as usual (I fill the alt field with a name and the name will appear in the source code page in order to be found by the seo).For the moment, I fill the alt field with a name but in the source code page nothing happened.More than that , the alt field respond if I fill the title field but that's not a solution for me.Also, don't want that alt= value to be visible on the page.Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: Is it possible that on certain images, the alt attribute simply does not exist in the database? Or is it with ALL images, no matter what?

Comment: It's not the case ,intentionally I have filled the alt field (from edit images menu) with values and the code is not running right (the value is not updated in the alt= code section from the page source).I know , it's beyond the normal rules of php :)

Comment: I just update the main question with more details .Hope this will help.thanks

Comment: If it works for you, post it as an answer and accept the answer. That's allowed here, and will help others because it's marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, a really good man gave me the solution.Nice, clean, simple.And for those who want to use this theme and to have alt="" function working properly as well , just replace the img alt="" content found on the tmpl_single.php with this line :

```
<img alt="'.get_post_meta($row_img->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true).'" src="'.$strThumb.'" />
```

. Many thanks to [Vlad](http://www.yup.ro/) and also many thanks to [Mamaduka](https://github.com/wpshower/expositio) the author of this wonderful Wordpress theme

Answer (score 0):

Alt is deprecated in modern world of html5 and semantics website. Using attr `<title>`. Its recommanded

Comment: The alt attribute is NOT deprecated, and it is essentially different from the title attribute. The title attribute appears as a tooltip whereas the alt attribute does not (in modern browsers). The purpose of alt is to provide information about the image if it fails to load and for the visually impaired.